# Jupyter-notebook Experience in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I can't replicate the experience with jupyter-notebook on VSCode in different machines. I have 2 Windows machines a windows server and my pc (both uses Remote Linux for development; I use a Remote Linux machine in Server for development and WSL2 on pc).

The versions of VSCode, Python & Jupyter extensions are the same in both the machines. The jupyter-notebook in the server provides a better experience (as shown in extension details, mainly it supports vim), which I cannot get on my pc.

About VSCode.

```
Version: 1.58.0 (user setup)
Commit: 2d23c42a936db1c7b3b06f918cde29561cc47cd6
Date: 2021-07-08T06:54:55.083Z
Electron: 12.0.13
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043
```

Jupyter Extension: `v2021.8.1013163132`
Python Extension: `v2021.6.944021595`

Snap of a *.ipynb* file in Server (which supports VIM & that I want to replicate)

[image: Jupyter notebook in Machine A]

Snap of the same in my pc (which don't support vim).

[image: Jupyter notebook in my pc]

I could not figure out what I am missing.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has the "vim" tag since Vim doesn't seem to be involved.

Comment: Do you use vrtualenv ? Although I suspect that's the answer is in: "both uses Remote Linux for development; I use a Remote Linux machine in Server for development and WSL2 on pc" . Which variant is failing?

Comment: @AlexYu, WSL2 is what failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preview native notebooks UI is available to everyone in VS Code Insiders and a fraction of users in VS Code Stable. If you are in VS Code stable, please see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Native-Notebook-Support-in-VS-Code#enabling-the-new-experience for instructions on how to opt into the preview native notebooks UI.